# Cannot resolve flyway-sbt with handshake_failure on CentOS7

Tags: scala, sbt, flyway

I got problem on my scala project with `flyway-sbt` plugin.

On `project/plugins.sbt` file, we have like following

```
addSbtPlugin("org.flywaydb" % "flyway-sbt" % "4.0.3")
resolvers += "Flyway" at "https://flywaydb.org/repo"
```

Then, I run following command to run

```
$ sbt -Dhttp.proxyHost=<proxy IP> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<proxy Port> run
```

But we got error, like this

```
[info] Loading project definition from /home/ysawada/collection-master/project
[info] Updating {file:/home/ysawada/collection-master/project/}collection-master-build...
[info] Resolving org.flywaydb#flyway-sbt;4.0.3 ...
[error] Server access Error: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure url=https://flywaydb.org/repo/org/flywaydb/flyway-sbt_2.10_0.13/4.0.3/flyway-sbt-4.0.3.pom
[warn]  module not found: org.flywaydb#flyway-sbt;4.0.3
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.flywaydb/flyway-sbt/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/4.0.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.flywaydb/flyway-sbt/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/4.0.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/ysawada/.ivy2/local/org.flywaydb/flyway-sbt/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/4.0.3/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/flywaydb/flyway-sbt_2.10_0.13/4.0.3/flyway-sbt-4.0.3.pom
[warn] ==== Flyway: tried
[warn]   https://flywaydb.org/repo/org/flywaydb/flyway-sbt_2.10_0.13/4.0.3/flyway-sbt-4.0.3.pom
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.flywaydb#flyway-sbt;4.0.3: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]          org.flywaydb:flyway-sbt:4.0.3 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          org.flywaydb:flyway-sbt:4.0.3 (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13) (/home/ysawada/collection-master/project/plugins.sbt#L1-2)
[warn]            +- default:collection-master-build:0.1-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.10, sbtVersion=0.13)
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.flywaydb#flyway-sbt;4.0.3: not found
        at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:313)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:191)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$updateEither$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:168)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:156)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:156)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:133)
        at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:57)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$4.call(Ivy.scala:65)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:93)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:78)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:97)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:58)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:48)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:65)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:128)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:125)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:156)
        at sbt.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:168)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1439)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1435)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$90.apply(Defaults.scala:1470)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$90.apply(Defaults.scala:1468)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:37)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1473)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1467)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:60)
        at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1490)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1417)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1369)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.flywaydb#flyway-sbt;4.0.3: not found
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q
```

I think that is from ssl issue, but I could not figured out..

It is used under proxy, so the proxy relates to this problem?
If anyone knows the settings related to this issue, please let me know that.

Comment: You could add the  `-Djavax.net.debug=all` flag to enable debugging of the SSL connection established. With the debug switched on, you might see what specific part of the handshake failed.

Comment: @AlexanderB Hi, Alex, thanks for your comment. I tried that flag, but I could not find out the detail reason why the error occurred...  https://gist.github.com/yasuharu519/e9c2174d16ff9c81623962b889bcd209 Does anyone find out why that happen?